# Access violation when deriving from TObject in a DLL

Tags: dll, c++builder

I'm absolutely baffled to see that the following minimal example in C++ Builder XE2 causes an access violation:

In a project consisting of an **executable** and a **DLL**:

**Project1.dll / Dummy.h:**

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Dummy : public TObject
{
public:
    __fastcall Dummy();
    __fastcall ~Dummy();
};
```

**Project1.dll / Dummy.cpp:**

```
__fastcall Dummy::Dummy()
: TObject()
{
}

__fastcall Dummy::~Dummy()
{
}
```

**Project2.exe / Unit1.cpp:**

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Dummy *d = new Dummy; // access violation occurs in constructor
    delete d;
}
```

Both projects created from scratch with default project options, both with VCL support. The access violation does not occur if `Dummy` does not inherit from `TObject`.

What am I doing wrong?

cheers
Hendrik

Comment: Maybe the DLL is a release build and Project2 a debug build or vica versa?

Comment: Good idea, but nope. Access violation in both debug and release build.

Comment: What is the state of `Project Options > Linker > Use dynamic RTL` and `Project Options > Packages > Build with runtime packages` for both projects?

Comment: Both projects: Link with dynamic RTL = true, Build with runtime packages = true, and the list of runtime packages seems to feature all packages installed on my system

Comment: can you try to uncheck `link with dynamic RTL` for the DLL and project and rebuild it?

Comment: still getting the access violation :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14633/discussion-between-hendrik-and-wouterh)

Comment: One more observation, fwiw: the actual access violation occurs inside a function called `_ClassCreate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code works if you replace `__declspec(dllexport)` with `PACKAGE`.

I've tested this in various project configuration, and it seemed to make the difference - no crash anymore. However, I was not able to delay load the DLL anymore.

Looks to me like a C++ Builder bug.